# Error with Java String in declaration in intellij

Tags: java, selenium, intellij-idea

I've updated my intellij to 2017.2.5 and imported all the projects. For some reason, declaration and constructors show some error with Strings. e.g. private String type = "abc"; and name = " xyz"; Error asks me to change it to java.lang.string as a solution.

Jdk is up to date. libraries are up to date, so what is the problem? Project structure looks ok. How do I fix this?

[image]

Comment: Post all code and errors here directly as text.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks, @hnefatl . Solution worked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just delete the line:

```
import org.apache.xpath.operations.String
```

This is causing a type conflict between `java.lang.String` (what you want) and an Apache class (which you probably don't want).